# If ${\left\| A \right\|_1} \le 1$ Can we prove that all ${\sigma _i}(A)\le 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A\in M_n$ and ${\left\| A \right\|_1} \le 1$ (the maximum column sum norm).

Can we prove that all ${\sigma _i}(A)\le 1$?

(${\sigma _i}(A)$ is singular value of $A$)

Comment: @Norbert - Why is this formula  true?

Comment: it is not, that's why i deleted it

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be some $m \times n$ real matrix. Let $\|A\|_1$ be the *maximim absolute column sum norm*, $\|A \|_\infty$ be the *maximim absolute row sum norm* and $\|A \|_2 = \sigma_{\max}$ be the *2-norm* or *spectral norm* ($\sigma_{\max}$ is the maximum singular value).
We have the following fundamental inequalities:
$$(i) \quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \|A \|_\infty \leq \|A \|_2 \leq \sqrt{m} \|A \|_\infty$$
$$(ii) \quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \|A \|_1 \leq \|A \|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|A \|_1$$
$$ \|A \|_2 \leq \sqrt{\|A \|_1 \|A \|_\infty} \quad (\text{some kind of Hölder's inequality})$$.

So we see that if you impose additionally that also $\|A \|_\infty \leq 1$ (i.e. row sum is also small) then your assertion holds.

However it's easy to construct (quadratic) matrices with small column sum but big row sum (and vice versa). And inequality $(i)$ (or $(ii)$ whatever you are starting with) forces the largest singular value to be big. More precisely the following matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0.99 & 0.99 & 0.99\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
fulfilles your condition but has singular value $1.71473$.